# State functions defining different intervals of a main function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the function $f(x) = 4|3x-1|+|6x+3|$

I am supposed to state the partial functions without the absolute value notation for the different intervals.

I know that for:

$$x\ge 1/3, f(x) = 18x-1$$
$$x < -1/2, f(x) = -18x+1$$

I reached this conclusion from calculating assuming $x<0, x \le 0$ and then adjusting for the coefficients for $x$.

However I am not sure how to calculate the function for the interval $-1/2 \le x < 1/3$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, in each case, just see what is the sign of each of the expressions in the absolute values. Then replace the expression with those signed expressions, and simplify. That's it.

Comment: Thank you Matti and Aryadeva for the edit.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. After I graphed the two abs expressions I got a better understanding of why I had to sign them the way required to join and simplify for the middle interval. Thanks!